# Java SDCH compressor/decompressor

Tags: java, google-chrome, compression, gzip, vcdiff

Someone knows a java library to decode/encode SDCH compression??? it has been created by Google and implemented in their Google Chrome web browser... so it will be a standard soon

Some links about it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Dictionary_Compression_Over_HTTP
http://google-opensource.blogspot.ie/2008/09/open-vcdiff-encoder-and-decoder-for-rfc.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDCH is the name of the standard which applies the [VCDIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCDIFF) compression algorithm to HTTP. The web page lists implementations. One is [Xdelta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta).